# overloading a simple = operator

Tags: c++, string, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload part of my class to a `string` and I can't get the overloading to work. Alternatively, I will also have a `long long` overload, but I just assume that it will be the same excepted for `long long` instead of `string`.

```
class FileData
{
public:
    string extensions_;                 
    unsigned long long containsBytes_;      
};

string& operator = (string& s , FileData& fd)
{
    s= fd.extensions_;
    return s;
}

string extName = fileVector[0];
```

The error I keep getting is ERROR:'operator=' must be a member function.
I also tried using istream but that also didn't work.

Anybody know how I could go about this?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough?

Comment: An (explicit) conversion operator or function would work. You can't add a function to `std::string` to make it take your class in assignment (or copy-construction, which is what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to assign to a string from your class, you'll need a *conversion operator*:

```
class FileData
{
public:

    // Conversion to string
    operator string() const {return extensions_;}

    string extensions_;                 
    unsigned long long containsBytes_;      
};
```

You can only overload the assignment operator as a member of your class, for the purpose of assigning *to* an object of that class.

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload the operator= of std::string. What you probably want is a cast operator:

```
    class FileData
    {
    public:
        string extensions_;
        unsigned long long containsBytes_;

        operator string()
        {
            return extensions_;
        }
    }
```