# overload C++ native variables

Tags: c++, types, overloading, native

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867531/overloading-a-simple-operator?rq=1) earlier about how to overload strings, But when I use the same formula for `unsigned long long` it doesn't work.

I tried a `typedef` but that didn't work either.

```
typedef unsigned long long i64;              

//a new class to hold extention types, and bytes. 
class FileData
{
public:
  //conversion operators
  operator string(){return extensions_;}
  operator i64() {return containsBytes_;}  
   string& operator= (FileData &);
  i64& operator= (FileData &);

  string extensions_;                        
  i64 containsBytes_;        
};

string &FileData::operator=(FileData& fd)
{
    return fd.extensions_;
}

i64 &FileData::operator=(FileData& fd)
{
    return fd.containsBytes_;
}
```

there are two errors in this code.

first one is on line 11:

> Error:cannot overload functions distinguished by return types alone

second one is on line 22,

> Error:declaration is incompatible with "std::string &FileData::operator=(FileData& fd)"(declared on line 17).

but if I delete any mention of the string conversion it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The first error message says exactly what the error is. The second is merely a consequence. The problem is unrelated to the implicit conversion operators.

Comment: Grrr. Don't paste line-numbered code please. Mark offending code points with comments. Nobody wants to copy your code, paste it into their rig, then spend the time to remove all the cruft.

Comment: @WhozCraig `:%s/^\s*\d*|//` – but I agree.

Comment: please provide a link to your previous question, and define "it still doesn't work".

Comment: @didierc His previous question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867531/overloading-a-simple-operator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867531/overloading-a-simple-operator?rq=1 it's here, what i mean was, the string conversion works, but now i am not sure how to fix the conversion for the unsigned long long

Comment: Just remove the both operators, you don’t need or want them.

Comment: The problematic code is the `operator =` overloading, not the conversion operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is these

```
FileData& operator= (string&);
FileData& operator= (i64&);

FileData& FileData::operator=(string& s)
{
    this->extensions_ = s;
    return *this;
}

FileData& FileData::operator=(i64& l)
{
    this->containsBytes_ = l;
    return *this;
}
```

You are confusing assignment with type conversion operators. Assignment operator is used when you want to assign something to **your class**. Not to make it compatible with string or long long

With assignment for string overloaded you can do this

```
FileData a;
string str;
a = str;  // This will set a.extensions_ to str, see above.
```

but not.

```
str = a;
```

Because assignment expects your class on the left hand side.

To do `str = a;` you need to overload conversion operators (). Which you have done.

```
operator string(){return extensions_;}
```

With those overloaded

```
str = a;   // This will set str to a.extensions_ See the difference?
```

Answer (score 0):

First error message

> Error:cannot overload functions distinguished by return types alone

These two functions have identical parameters and differ only in return types

```
string& operator= (FileData &);
i64& operator= (FileData &);
```

C++ can overload functions only, when they differ in parameters.

Second error message

> Error:declaration is incompatible with "std::string &FileData::operator=(FileData& fd)"(declared on line 17).

```
i64 &FileData::operator=(FileData& fd)
{
    return fd.containsBytes_;
}
```

This is a follow up to the first error. The C++ compiler ignored the second assignment operator, because there was no differing parameters. Now, you define an assignment operator, which is *incompatible* with the assignment operator declared first above.